# Unusual behavior when uploading through Vimeo API

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm using the streaming PUT option to upload videos through Vimeo.  One of my videos, about 8-MB, triggered some weird behavior and I'm not sure if it's a fluke or not.

I pushed the video in one go (no chunks).  Now, when I call `video.upload.verifyChunks`, I consistently get a 709 error (unable to access chunk list).  `video.upload.checkTicket` says I have a valid ticket still.  Trying to `complete` gives a 504 Gateway Timeout error.

What additional information do I need to provide, and what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

video.upload.verifyChunks is for the HTTP POST method (https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/upload#post)

To verify a file for streaming (https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/upload#streaming-step4) you make a PUT request to the upload endpoint, with the header `Content-Range: */*`

Comment: Good point.  I only called verifyChunks once the complete call failed, as a debugging step.  Any comments to that point?  Why is it 504'ing?

Comment: Timeout error is often a server problem. You should send a failed upload ticket to vimeo.com/help/contact, and I can dig further into it.